# PHP json_encode JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK with 5808e70581507

Tags: php, json, scientific-notation

Hi I'm experiencing some difficulties with the json_encode function in PHP.
I have an object with a hash (uniq ID) but it can have this format 5808e70581507 and because of the "e" surrounded with numbers I think json_encode is trying to set this fellow as an integer.

My object looks like this :

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 16
    [title] => userinf2
    [desc] => Travail →
    [startoff] => 2016-10-20 05:00:00
    [stop] => 2016-10-20 13:00:00
    [status] => 1
    [allDay] => 0
    [code_mode] => M
    [uid] => 31250
    [gid] => 502935
    [recurrence_id] => 
    [recurrence_mode] => 
    [recurrence_repeat_every] => 
    [recurrence_repeat_day] => 
    [recurrence_end_mode] => 
    [recurrence_end_date] => 
    [recurrence_end_number] => 
    [multiple_timeschedule_id] => 5808e70581507
    [start] => 2016-10-20 05:00:00
    [end] => 2016-10-20 13:00:00
    [color] => #7AE7BF
    [className] => working uid_31250 code_mode_M gid_502935
)
```

Is there a way to make this working as it is ?

The code :

```
  echo json_encode($events[6], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 

  var_dump($events[6]->multiple_timeschedule_id); // string(13)
```

Assignment code :

```
    function _oms_planning_planning_get()
{
    try {

        global $user;
        $intervenants = _oms_planning_get_cab_intervenants();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM planning_event WHERE 1=1 AND (';
        $params_sql = array();
        foreach ($intervenants as $key => $a_user) {
            $sql .= ' uid =:uid' . $key . ' OR ';
            $params_sql[':uid' . $key] = $a_user->uid;
        }
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, -3);
        $sql .= ')';

        $result = db_query($sql, $params_sql);

        $db_events = $result->fetchAll();
        $events = array_map(function ($db_event) use ($intervenants) {
            $db_event->start = $db_event->startoff;
            $db_event->end = $db_event->stop;
            $db_event->color = (isset($db_event->gid) && intval($db_event->gid) > 0) ?
                _oms_planning_planning_get_color_from_gid($db_event->gid) :
                _oms_planning_planning_get_color_from_uid($intervenants, $db_event->uid);
            $db_event->className = ($db_event->status == 1) ? 'working ' : 'idleness ';
            $db_event->className .= 'uid_' . $db_event->uid . ' ';
            $db_event->className .= 'code_mode_' . $db_event->code_mode . ' ';
            $db_event->className .= 'gid_' . $db_event->gid;
            return $db_event;
        }, $db_events);

        return $events;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

Mysql column type : multiple_timeschedule_id    varchar(200)    utf8_general_ci

Comment: Well, question is what internal data type _is_ actually used prior to the call to `json_encode()`. PHP is a weakly typed language, yes, but that does not mean that it has no internal types. So, is $obj->multiple_timeschedule_id a string or a numeric type?

Comment: as it is : it's a string(13)

Comment: I'm thinking about adding a letter at the beginning of my hash

Comment: Could you post the code with the assignment? PHP does not automatically switch types because of a call to `json_encode()`. There must be some reason for that.

Comment: Em, you _do_ realize that `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` explicitly tells the function`json_encode()` to encode numeric strings as numbers?

Comment: @arkascha 1. I edited my post. 2. yea I do realize I tend to use this everytime because on the javascript side I need number to be number and I don't want to parse each values in JS before using those.

Comment: OK, so the issue is that you explicitly tell it to convert numbers, but then want an exception. That obviously is something PHP cannot guess.

Comment: You should ensure that your types are the correct types in PHP before `json_encode`ing your data. No need to do it in Javascript after the fact, and no reason to rely on a blanket automagic like `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` which obviously *can* get it wrong. If you're getting data from the database as strings, either switch your database adapter to cast the values correctly, or do it manually/through an ORM.

Comment: I suggest you do _not_ use that flag, but explicitly typecast those numbers you want as numeric values before encoding the objects. That works, though it is a little effort. You could for example implement a simple class accepting a "non typecasted" object in the constructor.

Comment: Casting in integer every single values I want as integer seems to work. the flag JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK seems to be a bad habbit. Thanks everyone. If you're willing to post an answer I'll be glad to accept it/upvote.